# The inconsistency between the loss curve and metric curve?

Tags: deep-learning

I recently trained a classification model to recognize actions. Everything went right, but there are some inconsistencies between the loss curves and accuracy curves. The blue one in the **loss** graph is the testing loss; the purple one is the training loss. In the **metric** graph, the green curve is the training accuracy; the blue one is the testing accuracy.

As we can see, while the testing loss trends worse, the testing accuracy doesn't get worse.  This confuses me.  Is it normal in deep learning?  Does it have any explanation?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**X-Y problem**:

Most important is the discrepancy between training and testing accuracy: it appears that you've *seriously* over-fitted.  Somewhere around 1k (iterations?), your testing metrics (loss & accuracy) diverged to roughly level, while the training continued to conform to the training set.  Before you got to iteration 2k, the discrepancy showed that your model was no longer valid for general use.

**Actual question**:

**Accuracy** is the practical concern of whether the predicted classification is correct.  It's a simple metric: yes/no.  51% confident => yes; 99% confident => yes.

Your model achieved roughly 65% accuracy and leveled off.

**Loss** is the internal metric of how far off your prediction is.  A 51% sure prediction that's wrong is only 51% wrong, but a 99% sure prediction that's wrong is almost *twice* as wrong.  This drives back-propagation.

With this data set, as your model works to conform to the training set, its *binary* predictions on the test set are still roughly the same, but its confidence is getting farther from binary correctness.  It could be less sure of the correct answers, and/or more sure of its incorrect predictions.  Either will drive the loss function higher.